# Moving window group to other monitor

Tags: windows, windows-10, multiple-monitors, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcuts

**Synopsis**
When I undock and redock my laptop, arrangement of different applications on the multiple monitors is messed up. I've to spend valuable time (usually less than 2-3 minutes, isn't that annoying?) re-arranging those back.

I know about the keyboard shortcuts (<kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> and <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>) but they work on individual windows.

**Problem**
Is there a way to move all windows of an application to the other monitor?

**Example**
Chrome has two windows open as shown. How can both be moved?

[image: Chrome Windows]

Answer (score 1):

[Keyboard shortcut list for Windows 10](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ie/help/12445/windows-keyboard-shortcuts) does not contain such a feature.

Perhaps the more convenient way than you are currently using is to press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> once (Task view opens) and then drag & drop desired windows to another desktop. Since all the windows are visible at once in Task view, the decision/selection process may be faster than current one when you are using the keyboard only on active window.

Also, instead of keeping the windows on another monitor, consider keeping some of them on different deskop (second, third, ...). Such an arrangement isn't affected by docking/undocking and you can instantly switch desktops using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>/<kbd>→</kbd>. You can add new desktop using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> and populate it in abovementioned Task view.

---

**Edit:** Partial solution for your expectations is [Dexpot](http://www.dexpot.de/?id=features#multiplemonitors) (free for private use, otherwise paid) which allows you to switch desktops on one monitor, but keep the same apps on the other (see the Multiple Monitors feature). Test it to find whether you can customize it for your use.

Comment: This Win+Tab does not let you select multiple windows or let you more one to another monitor. However, I like the idea behind virtual desktops. I use them a lot on mac. What I don't like about them on Windows is that they all move together, i.e., you cannot be on desktop 1 on one monitor and desktop 2 on another.

Comment: @Farhan – please check edited answer, maybe there is a solution for you.